# Django models default function run for every current object

Tags: python, django, django-models

`models.py`

```
class Subscription(models.Model):
    
    #... many fields ...
    
    # I added this field when I already had many objects
    uniqueSubscriptionId = models.CharField(default=generateUniqueSubscription, max_length=30)
```

`generateUniqueSubscription`

```
from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string


def generateUniqueSubscription():

    return get_random_string(20)
```

The Problem is that, when I run migrations, all of my old objects get the same `uniqueSubscriptionId`. I want each and every single old object to get a unique `uniqueSubscriptionId`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did:

`models.py`

```
def updateOldSubscriptionObjs(apps, schema_editor):
    old_subscription_model = apps.get_model("app_label", "Profile")

    for obj in old_subscription_model.objects.all():
        obj.uniqueSubscriptionId = generateUniqueSubscription()
        obj.save()

class Subscription(models.Model):
    
    #... many fields ...
    
    # I added this field when I already had many objects
    uniqueSubscriptionId = models.CharField(default=generateUniqueSubscription, max_length=30)
```

Then I ran `makemigrations`:

`python manage.py makemigrations`

Then edited the latest migration file:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        # forget this
    ]

    operations = [
        # .... many things ...
        
        migrations.RunPython(updateOldProfileObjs)
    ]
```

Then ran `migrate`:

`python manage.py migrate`

And voila, all old objects got updated, and also, any new object will also get updated as I specified default.

If you are lazy like me, and don't want to do these things, then open django python shell:

`python manage.py shell`

and then execute this function in shell:

```
def updateOldSubscriptionObjs():

    for obj in Subscription.objects.all():
        obj.uniqueSubscriptionId = generateUniqueSubscription()
        obj.save()
```

I wish if there was some built-in django feature for this.